# Error: Auth UserPool not configured. in react native Project

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am installing aws-amplify I get this error when compiling. do you know how to solve it?

perform the following steps

```
npm install aws-amplify

amplify add analytics

amplify add auth

amplify push
```

https://docs.amplify.aws/react-native/build-a-backend/auth/set-up-auth/

But when I use identifyUser I get this message
Error: Auth UserPool not configured.

https://docs.amplify.aws/react-native/build-a-backend/more-features/analytics/identify-user/

this is enviroment

```
"@aws-amplify/react-native": "^1.0.9",
"aws-amplify": "^6.0.9",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.7",
```